# Unstash is throwing error while running Jenkins pipeline inside a node and then inside a container

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

while running below part of the code I am getting error...

```
stash(includes: 'inf.sh', name: 'inf')
stage('abc') {
    container('inf') {
        unstash(name: 'inf')
        sh "inf.sh"
    }
}
```

It was always running...nothing changed in the code....
How to fix it? or it comes with any plugin....

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.jclouds.s3.domain.ObjectMetadata.StorageClass.standard
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)
    at org.jclouds.s3.domain.ObjectMetadata$StorageClass.valueOf(ObjectMetadata.java:36)
    at    org.jclouds.s3.functions.ParseObjectMetadataFromHeaders.apply(ParseObjectMetadataFromHeaders.java:81)
    at org.jclouds.s3.functions.ParseObjectFromHeadersAndHttpContent.apply(ParseObjectFromHeadersAndHttpContent.java:48)
    at org.jclouds.s3.functions.ParseObjectFromHeadersAndHttpContent.apply(ParseObjectFromHeadersAndHttpContent.java:34)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:74)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.DelegatesToInvocationFunction.handle(DelegatesToInvocationFunction.java:156)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.DelegatesToInvocationFunction.invoke(DelegatesToInvocationFunction.java:123)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.s3.blobstore.S3BlobStore.getBlob(S3BlobStore.java:235)
    at org.jclouds.blobstore.internal.BaseBlobStore.getBlob(BaseBlobStore.java:217)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.artifact_manager_jclouds.JCloudsArtifactManager.unstash(JCloudsArtifactManager.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.StashManager.unstash(StashManager.java:155)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.stash.UnstashStep$Execution.run(UnstashStep.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.stash.UnstashStep$Execution.run(UnstashStep.java:65)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

tries upgrading aws plugin...then tried keeping the inf.sh file empty ...it just doesn't work....